# Calling function before or after API is fully loaded

Tags: javascript

I have a button and if it is clicked I need to call a function that hides another element that is initialized by a js file that is asynchronously loaded. However, the only way I can hide the element is via a Javacsript API. There is not an ID or class assigned to the iframe that is created via the API so I am forced to use the JS API for that script.

When my button is clicked I execute the following code:

```
if(typeof Tawk_API.hideWidget === "function"){
  Tawk_API.hideWidget();
}else{
  Tawk_API.onLoad = function(){
      Tawk_API.hideWidget();
  };
}
```

This function successfully hides the widget if it is loaded already and adds an onLoad if it hasn't been loaded yet.

I know that Javascript isn't multithreaded, but is there a reason that the processor might hand over the main thread to loading the async js file right in the middle of my function which could potentially cause my condition to fail? I want to ensure that the `js` file won't load while my function is executing the `else` which would prevent my script from properly hiding the widget.

Comment: `JavaScript isn't multi-threaded` and `processor hand over the main thread` cannot both be true. The flow of execution doesn't just randomly jump forward or backward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Javascript engine will execute all the synchronous code in a blocking manner, until it reaches an operation that is asynchronous (I/O, network call, etc). Then after starting this async operation, it will return executing more synchronous code. Should the async operation finish during such synchronous code, the callback will only be called when the blocking section has been fully executed.

So your code is safe :)

Answer (score 2):

You can be sure that this code is correct.

Learn more about [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) in JavaScript